# Add a corner to bordered div

Tags: html, css

I need to recreate a responsive (and preferrably not a sprite-) version of [**this image**](https://arma-social-club.de/themes/Tattoo/images/header-top.png).

I already created [**this**](http://demo.tesserakt.pro/asc/stoff/) but I don't know how to add the 45-degree corner you can see on the right side of the image. Anyone has an Idea of how to do this?

//EDIT: Many people linked stuff to the "stichted look" or the "css arrows". I know how to do both but I need to combine them and this is the hard part.

Comment: Try searching for `css arrows`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bcGdJ/1/ - check this

Comment: Right now, this right here is the proof that StackOverflow was not useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the shapes pretty quickly see the code below. The hard part is the dotted stitch lines; you might have to either lest those go or make them a repeating border pattern. The background you an use as a repeating pattern, no worries.

See this code:

```css
.rectangle {
background: green;
position: relative;
width: 80%;
height: 120px;
}

.arrow-right {
position: absolute;
right: -60px;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 60px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;

  border-left: 60px solid green;
}

.rectangle-two {
background: red;
width: 80%;
height: 120px;
display: inline-block;
}

.arrow-right-two {
display: inline-block;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 60px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
  border-left: 60px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle"><div class="arrow-right"></div></div>

<div class="rectangle-two"></div><div class="arrow-right-two"></div>
```

Comment: The main problemm is probably to add a background to the border.

Comment: BAckground is simple, the border is not.

Comment: Have a look at this for the stitched look in css: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/stitched-look/

Answer (score 0):

Best I can think of is something like the below. Responsively it will be hard, I'd use an svg for the border that way it would grow and shrink with the box. You could also use clip path rather than an svg to clip the corner but it won't work in edge 14.

```css
.corner-cutoff {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: green;
    border: 3px dashed white;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 500px;
    width: 300px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px green, 2px 1px 6px 4px rgba(10, 10, 0, 0.5);
}

.corner-cutoff .corner {
    position: absolute;
    top: -11px;
    right: 19px;
    height: 64px;
    width: 1px;
    background-color: green;
    border-left: 3px dashed white;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.corner-cutoff svg {
    height: 66px;
    width: 66px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -13px;
    top: -13px;
}

.corner-cutoff svg .image-cut-shape {
    fill: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="corner-cutoff">
    <div class="corner">
    </div>
    <svg id="corner-svg" data-name="Layer 1" class="svg-image-cut"
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 490 490">
        <polygon class="image-cut-shape" points="0 0 490 0 490 490 0 0"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best I can do

https://jsfiddle.net/b8hpe75b/1/

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.box {
   padding: 20px;
   margin: 10px;
   background: #ff0030;
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 21px;
   font-weight: bold;
   line-height: 1.3em;
   border-top: 2px dashed #fff;
   border-bottom: 2px dashed #fff;
   border-left: 2px dashed #fff;
   border-radius: 10px;
   //box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #ff0030, 2px 1px 6px 4px rgba(10, 10, 0, 0.5);
   box-shadow: -3px 0px 0px 3px #ff0030;
   //text-shadow: -1px -1px #aa3030;
   font-weight: normal;
   width: 200px;
   z-index: 1;
   position: relative;
}

.triangle {
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
   background: red;
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 21px;
   font-weight: bold;
   line-height: 1.3em;
   border-top: 2px dashed #fff;
   border-right: 2px dashed #fff;
   border-radius: 10px;
   //box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #ff0030, 2px 1px 6px 4px rgba(10, 10, 0, 0.5);
   //text-shadow: -1px -1px #aa3030;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px #ff0030;
   font-weight: normal;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY( -50% ) rotate(45deg);
   right: 0;
   z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="triangle">
  </div>
</div>
```